# checking whether the C compiler works... no

Tags: ruby, xcode, gcc, compiler-construction, rvm

I recently uninstalled Xcode 4.2 and re-installed Xcode 4.3.1. Installed `Command Line Tools` also. The error says 'C compiler doesn't work`. On searching for this error, it said that it happens when Xcode is not installed. What am I missing?

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/ava/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-preview1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-preview1 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-preview1 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-preview1 to /Users/ava/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-preview1
ruby-1.9.3-preview1 - #extracted to /Users/ava/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-preview1
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/ava/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/ava/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/ava/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/ava/.rvm/usr"  --with-gcc=clang           --build=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0           --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0           --build=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0           --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0 ', please read /Users/ava/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/ava/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
ERROR: Error running '/usr/bin/make ', please read /Users/ava/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/yaml/make.log
Installing yaml to /Users/ava/.rvm/usr
ERROR: Error running '/usr/bin/make install', please read /Users/ava/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/yaml/make.install.log
ruby-1.9.3-preview1 - #configuring 
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/ava/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-preview1 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc  --with-gcc=clang           --build=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0           --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0           --build=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0           --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0 --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/ava/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/ava/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/configure.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.


➜  yaml git:(master) ✗ vi configure.log 

[2012-03-18 21:03:00]  ./configure --prefix="/Users/ava/.rvm/usr"  --with-gcc=clang           --build=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0           --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0           --build=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0           --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-gcc
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/ava/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ gcc -v   
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.9~22/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.9~22/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)


➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Comment: Can you simply pass `CC=clang` as an environment variable on the command line to `configure` or whatever invokes it?

Comment: you mean like this on Terminal? `➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ CC=clang
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ `

Answer (score 23):

In the Terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Also, in Xcode, make sure the Command Line Tools are installed. Choose Xcode > Preferences, click on Downloads, and if necessary, click the Install button next to "Command Line Tools".

Comment: `➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
Password:
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗     ` Nothing happens.

Comment: `xcode-select` doesn't print anything, true, but does the build work after you did it?  You didn't say whether you tried again.

Comment: This article helped me out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13595772/1008519
It creates a symbolic link so the compiler is able to find the toolchain

Comment: Worked for me. I had a developer preview and another version isntalled.

Answer (score 8):

1. you use old RVM which does not know about latest ruby pathclevel, update with `rvm get head`
2. Ruby is not yet fully ready for LLVM, your get best chances for compilation using osx-gcc-installer and `--with-gcc=gcc-4.2`

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 can be compiled with clang.

Comment: yes but only 1.9.3-p125 and it still has issues, I heard that 1.9.3-head is better - but still not everything

Comment: I managed to install `ruby-1.9.3 p484` with `gcc-4.9` with following command: `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484 --with-gcc=gcc-4.9` Thanks for sharing this comment; it was useful!

Comment: +1 for `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484 --with-gcc=gcc-4.9` for resolving the `checking whether the C compiler works... no` problem.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by running :

```
rvm install <ruby-version> --with-gcc=clang
```

Replace < ruby-version> with version you want to use

Answer (score 2):

For those out there running into the same problem,

System (in order of installation)

- OSX 10.7.3
- RVM
- XCode 4.3
- Developer Tools (through XCode Preferences > Downloads)
- [OSX-GCC-Installer-10.7](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/)

**I had set LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS to point to Homebrew installations, this resulted in errors**. I "unlinked" LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS, ran 'rvm install 1.9.2' and everything worked fine.

- rvm install 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Try `./configure --without-gcc` to use clang.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mavericks and the provided answers didn't work for me. However, updating my version of Xcode and making sure Command Line Tools are installed did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier to install by using the compiler the system knows about

```
1. rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p547 --with-gcc=`echo which gcc`
```