# Problems with compiling apache2 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, apache

While trying to compile the latest version of the apache web server(2.4.3) on my Mac (10.8) I run into a problem. When I run the ./configure command I got the following output:

```
checking for chosen layout... Apache
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
configure: 
configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library...
configure: 
checking for APR... yes
  setting CC to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc"
  setting CPP to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -E"
  setting CFLAGS to " "
  setting CPPFLAGS to " -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK"
  setting LDFLAGS to " "
configure: 
configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime Utility library...
configure: 
checking for APR-util... yes
checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/cti/Downloads/Applications/httpd-2.4.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Here are the last few lines in the log file:

```
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3056: checking for chosen layout
configure:3058: result: Apache
configure:3861: checking for working mkdir -p
configure:3877: result: yes
configure:3886: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:3944: result: /usr/bin/grep
configure:3949: checking for egrep
configure:4011: result: /usr/bin/grep -E
configure:4027: checking build system type
configure:4041: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
configure:4061: checking host system type
configure:4074: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
configure:4094: checking target system type
configure:4107: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
configure:4137: 
configure:4139: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library...
configure:4141: 
configure:4182: checking for APR
configure:4327: result: yes
configure:4587: 
configure:4589: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime Utility library...
configure:4591: 
configure:4628: checking for APR-util
configure:4707: result: yes
configure:4968: checking for gcc
configure:4995: result: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
configure:5224: checking for C compiler version
configure:5233: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc --version >&5
./configure: line 5235: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
configure:5244: $? = 127
configure:5233: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -v >&5
./configure: line 5235: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
configure:5244: $? = 127
configure:5233: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -V >&5
./configure: line 5235: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
configure:5244: $? = 127
configure:5233: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -qversion >&5
./configure: line 5235: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
configure:5244: $? = 127
configure:5264: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:5286: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK   conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 5288: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
configure:5290: $? = 127
configure:5328: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:5333: error: in `/Users/cti/Downloads/Applications/httpd-2.4.3':
configure:5335: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

As you can see in the log output the script in ./configure couldn't find the path to my C compiler because it's in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/cc` and not in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc`as it's stated in the log output
You may say that the solution is simple all I have to do is to modify the configure script, right?? well the problem with that is that I know nothing about shell script which is why I've been struggling with it for the last 3 hours.
Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes I did but there is nothing in there that can help me.

Comment: Well then maybe it can help us help you? Please edit your question to include the last few lines if the log file.

Comment: I add the last few lines of the log file as you requested, please take a look and tell me what you think

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I was just struggling with a similar issue in [this post I created and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595730/how-do-i-build-mod-jk-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/13595732#13595732) so I thought I would share my findings. Simply create the symlink by doing this:

```
# Create a symlink to default Xcode toolchain for OS X lion
sudo ln -s \
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain \
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain

# Create a symlink to default Xcode toolchain for OS X maverick
sudo ln -s \
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain \
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain
```

and you should at least get to the next step.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian you've just saved my life :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian you just saved my life :)

Comment: It looks like APR-Util / APR (portable environment for compiling different products based on shared libraries) is broken in Mountain Lion. It links to the wrong compilers. Anyone know how to switch these? For instance for apxs, you can run apxs -c -S cc=/usr/bin/gcc etc

Comment: Great tip! Life saver!

Comment: One might need to replace OSX10.8 with OSX10.9 for Maverick

Comment: In the dark forest of environment setup I found your ray of light life-saving :) Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

For OSX 10.9 Mavericks Apache is already installed, you can directly go to the terminal and type in the following commands

To Find the Apache Version

```
httpd -v
```

To start :

```
sudo apachectl start
```

To stop :

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

To restart :

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm on OSX Mavericks and was trying to compile Apache 2.2.24 and ran into this error.  I saw from other answers that the problem was with apxr and thus APR returning the wrong location for gcc.  Apple supplies this and the Apache config was using the Apple supplied one.

On a whim, I looked and saw that the configure script has an option to ignore the system supplied APRs and use its own.

So I did this:

```
./configure --with-included-apr
```

And it got past the configure step and compiled without errors.

Comment: For this to work you need to download the apache apr library. E.g. like this `cd srclib/; curl http://wwwftp.ciril.fr/pub/apache//apr/apr-1.5.1.tar.gz | tar xvz; curl http://wwwftp.ciril.fr/pub/apache//apr/apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz | tar xvz; mv apr-1.5.1 apr; mv apr-util-1.5.4 apr-util; cd apr; configure; make; cd .. ; cd apr-util; configure; make; cd .. ; cd ..`

Answer (score 2):

```
checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc accepts -g... yes
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -E
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking for pcre-config... false

configure: error: pcre-config for libpcre not found. PCRE is required and available from http://pcre.org/
```

====

I've downloaded the pcre-config, ran: `./configure;make;make install`

and now..... Tcharammmm! Httpd apache full installed :D

Comment: Is that an answer to this question (or) a different problem and the way you solved it? If the latter, post it as a different question and add your own answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

`OSX Yosemite (10.10.5)`:

The accepted answer worked for me:

```
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains

$ ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/ OSX10.10.xctoolchain
                   ^                      ^
                   |                      |
             existing dir(or file)     link name
```

(Explanation of why that works below.)

Then:

```
httpd-2.4.18$ ./configure  (php may require an additional option)
```

***If you are also going to install php***, you may need to add another option to ./configure.

The basic instructions for [installing php on Unix](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) also give instructions on how to install apache:

```
./configure --enable-so
make
make install
```

Apache's configuration help says this:

```
httpd-2.4.18$ ./configure --help 
...
...
--enable-so    DSO capability. This module will be automatically
               enabled unless you build all modules statically.
```

That seems to indicate that the `--enable-so` option might be a default option, but the apache install instructions do not even mention `--enable-so`.  In the apache **2.2** docs for [configure](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/configure.html#configurationoptions), I found this:

```
Modules, disabled by default
Some modules are compiled by default and have to be enabled explicitly...
...
...
--enable-so
...
```

The apache **2.4** docs for [configure](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/configure.html) do not mention --enable-so.  Instead, they tell you to look at the output of `./configure --help` under `Optional features`, which lists --enable-so.

As a result, I think you should configure apache like this:

```
 httpd-2.4.18$ ./configure --enable-so
```

========

**INSTALLING PHP**

In order to get mysql to work with php, I had to reinstall php and change the following line in the php install docs:

```
php-7.0.2$ ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql
```

to:

```
php-7.0.2$ ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-pdo-mysql
```

With the first one, the configure output said that the `--with-mysql` option doesn’t exist--otherwise php installed fine, and php files in apache's `htdocs directory` were executed by php.

The problem is that php has changed its mysql support, and `mysql_connect()` is deprecated(and removed from php7), so now you need the `pdo-mysql adapter`, as described in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

After reinstalling php, the last lines of `make install` said this:

```
You may want to add: /usr/local/lib/php to your php.ini include_path
```

`php.ini` is located here: `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`, and I made that change:

```
include_path = ".:/php/includes:/usr/local/lib/php"
```

Then I restarted apache, made sure mysql was running, and I entered the following url in my browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/mysql_test.php
```

and my test PDO script worked (located in the directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs):

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$password = ’root_password_here’;
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'my_db';


$pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname", 
    $user,
    $password
);

$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);

?>
```

===========

After getting the same error message as the op, I checked `config.log` in the `httpd-2.4.18` directory, and a line in there says:

```
./configure: line 5326: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: 
No such file or directory
```

So the configure script is looking for:

1. A directory named:

   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
   Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin/`
2. A file named `cc` in that directory.

Okay, let's see if `cc` is in that directory:

```
~$ cd/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin/

-bash: cd: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin/: No such file or directory
```

That means the directory does not exist. Now you have to figure out which directory in that long path is the one that doesn't exist:

```
~$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app
/Applications/Xcode.app$ cd Contents/Developer
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer$ cd Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain

-bash: cd: Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/: No such file or directory

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer$ cd Toolchains
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains$ ls 

XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
```

You can see that there is no directory named `OSX10.10.xctoolchain`--there is only a directory named `XcodeDefault.xctoolchain`. As a result, the configure script can't locate the directory `OSX10.10.xctoolchain` in the path that it is using to find the `cc` file.  Why is `configure` looking for that directory?  Because either the dev who wrote the script screwed up or Apple screwed up.

The real goal of `configure` is not to find a directory but to find the pesky `cc` file.  It turns out that the `cc` file is located here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin$ ls
...
cc
clang       
...
...
```

And for the more curious:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin$ ls -al cc

lrwxr-xr-x  1 7stud  admin  5 Oct 29 15:22 cc -> clang
```

`cc` is just a link to Xcode's clang compiler.

The accepted answer creates a link from the name `OSX10.10.xctoolchain` to the directory that actually contains the `cc` file (albeit several directories deeper) `XcodeDefault.xctoolchain`:

```
Applications/
  Xcode.app/
    Contents/
      Developer/
        Toolchains/
          XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/
          OSX10.10.xctoolchain/ -> XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/
            usr/
              bin/
                 cc
```

In other words, after creating the link the two paths:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

will be equivalent.  The names `XcodeDefault.xctoolchain` and `OSX10.10.xctoolchain` will be aliases for the same directory.

====

I don't understand `@AlphaZygma's answer`. It advises adding the following two directories to your PATH (via /etc/paths):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

1. On my system, the first directory does not contain a `cc` file, so there's no reason for me to add that directory to my PATH.
2. The second directory is the directory that configure says it can't find.   Adding a non-existent directory to your PATH still means it's non-existent.
3. In any case, the configure script does not seem to be searching the PATH directories for `cc` because the error message lists a non-exist path as the problem.  How would searching the PATH directories result in the error message listing a non-existent path?  The configure script seems to be getting directions from somewhere else telling it where to search for `cc`.
4. I'm not sure why @AlphaZygma inserted the new paths between some of the existing paths in `/etc/paths`. Why not add the new paths below the existing paths?

I tried several different versions of this answer, but nothing worked for me.

====

I looked at the output of `./configure --help`:

```
Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

...
...

Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
```

Hey, CC is listed there.  Let's try:

```
$ ./configure CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc

...
...

checking for APR... yes
  setting CPP to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -E"
  setting CFLAGS to " "
  setting CPPFLAGS to " -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10"
  setting LDFLAGS to " "
configure: 
...
...
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Looking at the output a little more carefully there is this line:

```
      setting CPP to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
OSX10.10.xctoolchain
```

The configure script is still mentioning that non-existent path in conjunction with CPP.  Looking at the output of `./configure --help` again:

```
Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

...
...

Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
```

The last line lists the variable CPP, which was mentioned in the error line.  Let's try:

```
$ ./configure \
> CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc \
> CPP=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc 

...
...

checking how to run the C preprocessor... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
configure: error: in `/Users/7stud/Downloads/httpd-2.4.18':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
```

Now all the paths are correct in the error message, but something "fails sanity check". I give up!  Maybe someone else can pick up where I left off.

Okay, thanks to the suggestions [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2004-06/msg00256.html), the following works:

```
$ ./configure \
> CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc \
> CPP='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -E'
```

and that can be shortened to:

```
$ ./configure \
> CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc \
> CPP='cc -E'
```

But then `make` failed:

```
$ make
...
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool: line 8962: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
```

Once again the non-existent path is mentioned--this time in conjunction with `libtool`. That's as far as I'm going down that rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into same issue, on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks); yes as user3097424 states, Apache is pre-installed for Mavericks users, though for me, version 2.2. Therefore, needing to upgrade to 2.4, do as Adrian Rodriguez says and create a symlink, replacing '10.8' with '10.9':

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a symlink, you could just add the path to your library path, just use the appropriate directories to your OSX Version.

So, in your case, it may look like

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo vi /etc/paths
/usr/bin
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin
/bin
...
```

I think this approach is a bit cleaner without having to add symlinks in different places as expected by different tools.

Anyway, this is just an alternate solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `OSX Yosemite(10.10.5) `: After getting the same error as the op, I checked `config.log` in the `httpd-2.4.18` directory, and it said:  `./configure: line 5326: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory`.  I'm not sure how adding a non-existent directory to my PATH will help the configure script find the `cc` file.

Answer (score 0):

@AlphaZygma this worked great for me. I'm on 10.8.5 and had to add the following to `/etc/paths`:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

instead of yours.

Comment: `OSX Yosemite(10.10.5)`:  The second directory exists for me, but I'm not sure how that makes configure look for `cc` in that directory instead of the non-existent directory: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/b‌​in/` which config.log says is the reason for my error.

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution that allowed me to pass through:

```
checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

issue can be found here:
http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/apache/

The command are (some needs sudo su):

```
cd /usr/local/src (mkdir /usr/local/srt if /usr/local/src doesnt exist)
curl --remote-name http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/apache/httpd/httpd-2.4.9.tar.gz
tar -xzvf httpd-2.4.9.tar.gz
rmhttpd-2.4.9.tar.gz
cd httpd-2.4.9

sudo xcode-select -switch /
mkdir -p /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin (this might require sudo su)
ln -s /usr/bin/cc /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc (this might require sudo su)

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache-2.4.9
make
make install

ln -s apache-2.4.9 /usr/local/apache
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as the accepted answer.   It turns out that `cc` is also located in /usr/bin as well as  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/. This answer just symlinks the name `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc`, which is what the configure script is looking for but can't find, to /usr/bin/cc rather than the existing `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc`

Answer (score 0):

I just recently updated to Mavericks and was re-creating my web development environment (including installing port). I had this problem when I was upgrading port:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

I thought I had everything setup, including installing XCode from the App Store.  But kept having issues.  I was able to fix it by actually running XCode once, accepting the license agreement, and letting XCode startup fully.  The next time I tried to upgrade port I did not get the error above.